# ACF: *protected email* in Output

Tags: php, wordpress, encode, advanced-custom-fields

I have a Wordpress-Site and i am working with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) right now.

After reading this http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

I started to output the Fields that i wanted to show up on the single-archive.php like this:

```
the_field('name');
```

This worked well and i did the same things on the other outputs.
But i run into a problem when i was trying to output the email.
If i try to output the email-field like this:

```
the_field('email_adresse');
```

The result is `*protected email*`

So i googled it and found this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-email-address-encoder-encoding-e-mails-from-custom-fields

On this page the Plugin Author says the fix is:

```
<p><a href="<?php echo eae_encode_str('mailto:'.get_field('mail')); ?>"><?php echo eae_encode_str(get_field('mail')); ?></a></p>
```

But if i insert i get this error where it tells me that the function eae_encode_str doesn't exist.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function eae_encode_str() in C:\Users\Hadorn AG\Documents\Websites\www.dance-vision.dev\wp-content\themes\_dancevision\single-annonce.php
```

Is there a plugin for this or is there another way to fix the e-mail output from ACF?

I hope i gave enough Information on my Problem :).
If not let me know and i add if something is needed.

Thanks for any help and i wish you a beautifull day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... :P, the Plugin Authors fix had some syntax error.
Here is the fix if someone has the same problem.

Step 1: https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-address-encoder/faq/

Step 2: Output the E-Mail like this:

```
echo '<a href="';
echo eae_encode_str('mailto:'.get_field('mail'));
echo '">';
echo eae_encode_str(get_field('email_adresse'));
echo '</a>';
```

i wish you a beautifull day :)